# react data grid sticky header using MUI datagrid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, datagrid

If I use the scroll which is the global vertical scroll outside and scroll below or at the bottom then column header of the table should be stick so that even I am at the bottom I could still see the column headers.

Anyone has an idea how we can implement this one ? especially that I used pinned tables. Please see my sample sanbox. Thanks.

[image]
https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-frost-13y5td?file=/src/PortfolioPage/PortfolioPage.jsx

#snippet

```
export const StyledDataGrid = styled(DataGrid)`
        .MuiDataGrid-row: nth-of-type(odd) {
          background: #E3E0E0
        }
        .MuiDataGrid-cell {
          border-right: 1px solid #C4C4C4;
        }
        .MuiDataGrid-columnHeader  {
          border-right: 1px solid #C4C4C4;
        }
        .MuiDataGrid-columnSeparator--sideRight {
          display: none
        }
        .MuiDataGrid-columnHeaderTitleContainer {
          justify-content: space-between;
        }
        .MuiDataGrid-iconButtonContainer  {
          visibility: visible;
          width: auto;
        }
    `;
    
    const Page: FC = () => {
      
    
      const columns: GridColDef[] = [
        {
          field: "associateDirectorofConstructionOps",
          headerName: "Associate Director of Construction Ops",
          minWidth: 300,
          flex: 0.16,
          disableColumnMenu: true,
          renderCell: (params: GridRenderCellParams<string>) => (
            <>
               {
                 params.row.associateDirectorofConstructionOps ? params.row.associateDirectorofConstructionOps.map((prop: IEmail) => renderList(prop))
                  : null
               }
            </>
          ),
        },
      ];
      const fixedColumnLeft: GridColDef[] = [
        {
          field: "regionName",
          headerName: "Region Division",
          flex: 0.08,
          minWidth: 100,
          disableColumnMenu: true,
        },
        {
          field: "subRegionName",
          headerName: "Sub-Region",
          flex: 0.15,
          minWidth: 50,
          disableColumnMenu: true,
        },
        {
          field: "marketName",
          headerName: "Market",
          flex: 0.08,
          minWidth: 50,
          disableColumnMenu: true,
        },
      ];
      const fixedColumnRight: GridColDef[] = [
        {
          field: "action",
          disableColumnMenu: true,
          sortable: false,
          renderHeader: () => <></>,
          renderCell: (params: GridRenderCellParams<string>) => (
            <div
              style={{
                color: "rgb(110 110 110)",
                display: "flex",
                justifyContent: "space-between",
              }}
            >
              <EditIcon onClick={() => handleClickOpen(params)} />
            </div>
          ),
        },
      ];
      const [open, setOpen] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
      const handleClickOpen = (data: any) => {
        setSelectedRow(data.row);
        setOpen(true);
      };
    
      const handleClose = () => {
        setOpen(false);
      };
      return (
        <Box sx={{ height: "100vh", background: "#EEEAEA" }}>
          <Snackbar
            open={snackbarOpen}
            autoHideDuration={3000}
            onClose={() => setSnackbarOpen(false)}>
            <Alert onClose={() => setSnackbarOpen(false)} severity="success" sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
                  Successfully saved!
            </Alert>
          </Snackbar>
          <EditProperties open={open} handleClose={handleClose} selectedRow={selectedRow} />
          <DashboardWrapper seoProps={{
            title: "PIM | Regions",
            }}
            title="Properties"
            mainClass="properties-page">
            {isError ? <div>Error Loading Regions!</div> : ""}
            {isPending ? <>Loading Regions...</> : ""}
            {isSuccess ? (
            <>
                <div
                  style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    justifyContent: "space-between",
                    width: "636px",
                    height: "56px",
                    background: "rgba(37, 36, 41, 0.9)",
                    padding: "8px 16px 8px 8px",
                    borderBottomRightRadius: "30px",
                  }}
                >
                  <Input
                    size="small"
                    style={{
                      width: "461px",
                      height: "40px",
                      background: "#FFFFFF",
                      borderRadius: "4px",
                      outline: "none",
                    }}
                    placeholder="Search  by typing property name or address"
                    startAdornment={
                      <InputAdornment position="start">
                        <SearchIcon />
                      </InputAdornment>
                    }
                  />
                  <Button
                    variant="contained"
                    style={{ textTransform: "capitalize" }}
                  >
                    Search
                  </Button>
                  <div
                    style={{
                      display: "flex",
                      color: "#FFFFFF",
                      flexDirection: "column",
                      justifyContent: "space-between",
                      alignItems: "center",
                      marginRight: "10px",
                    }}
                  >
                    <TuneIcon style={{ fontSize: "32px" }} />
                    <span style={{ fontSize: "10px", marginTop: "-5px" }}>
                      Filters
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <TableContainer component={Paper} style={{ marginTop: "24px" }}>
                  <div
                    style={{
                      borderBottom: "1px solid #C4C4C4",
                      padding: "16px",
                      display: "flex",
                      justifyContent: "space-between",
                      background: "#FFFFFF",
                      height: "72px",
                    }}
                  >
                    <label
                      style={{
                        fontWeight: "600",
                        fontSize: "24px",
                        color: "#252429",
                        alignSelf: "center",
                      }}
                    >
                      {" "}
                      Regions{" "}
                    </label>
                    <div
                      style={{
                        alignSelf: "center",
                        color: "#C4C4C4",
                        display: "flex",
                        fontSize: "16px",
                      }}
                    >
                      <IosShareIcon style={{ marginRight: "14px" }} />
                      Export
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  {/* Table container */}
                  <div style={{position: "relative", display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
                      {/* Left table */}
                      <Box
                        sx={{ boxShadow: 5 }}
                        style={{
                          width: "20%",
                       
                          zIndex: 99,
                          overflow: "hidden",
                          background: "#FFFFFF",
                        }}
                      >
                        <StyledDataGrid
                          autoHeight 
                          getRowId={(row) => row.accountId}
                          hideFooterPagination={true}
                          components={{
                            ColumnSortedAscendingIcon: UnfoldMoreIcon,
                            ColumnSortedDescendingIcon: UnfoldMoreIcon,
                          }}
                          rows={rows}
                          columns={fixedColumnLeft}
                          disableSelectionOnClick
                          experimentalFeatures={{ newEditingApi: true }}
                        />
                      </Box>
    
                      {/* Center table */}
                    <div style={{overflow: 'hidden', width: '70%'}}>
                      <div style={{ width: '2000px', margin: 'auto', overflow: "hidden"}} >
                        <StyledDataGrid
                          autoHeight 
                          getRowId={(row) => row.accountId}
                          components={{
                            ColumnSortedAscendingIcon: UnfoldMoreIcon,
                            ColumnSortedDescendingIcon: UnfoldMoreIcon,
                          }}
                          rows={rows}
                          columns={columns}
                          pageSize={100}
                          rowsPerPageOptions={[10, 20, 50, 100]}
                          disableSelectionOnClick
                          experimentalFeatures={{ newEditingApi: true }}
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>
    
                      {/* Right table */}
                      <Box
                        sx={{ boxShadow: 5 }}
                        style={{
                          width: "10%",
                          zIndex: 99,
                          overflow: "hidden",
                          background: "#FFFFFF",
                        }}
                      >
                        <StyledDataGrid
                          autoHeight 
                          getRowId={(row) => row.accountId}
                          hideFooterPagination={true}
                          components={{
                            ColumnSortedAscendingIcon: UnfoldMoreIcon,
                            ColumnSortedDescendingIcon: UnfoldMoreIcon,
                          }}
                          rows={rows}
                          columns={fixedColumnRight}
                          disableSelectionOnClick
                          experimentalFeatures={{ newEditingApi: true }}
                        />
                      </Box>
                  </div>
                </TableContainer>
                {/* <ActionButtonContainer
                  btnNameOne="Property"
                  btnNameTwo="Properties"
                  btnIconOne={<UploadFileIcon />}
                  btnIconTwo={<AddIcon />}
                /> */}
              </>
            ) : (
              ""
            )}
          </DashboardWrapper>
        </Box>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can override "MuiDataGrid-columnHeaders" class in theme or use styled component, and add this to it:

```
 position: "sticky"
```

and add this :

```
 marginTop: "0 !important"
```

to "MuiDataGrid-virtualScrolle" class

Comment: can you be more spefic on where I can add it? Thanks.